# Complex Analysis: Proof by contradiction of the "Radius of Convergence Theorem"

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-explanation, power-series

H.A. Priestley in "Introduction to Complex Analysis" page 73 gives two proofs of the "Radius of Convergence lemma". The first seems to turn on the difference between Convergence and Absolute Convergence and though it seems to be almost arguing in circles I can just about see how it works. The second proof, though, which is by contradiction, I do not see at all.

For the contradiction, Priestley puts forward some $z$ with $\vert z|>R$ for which $\sum c_n z^n$ converges. Then, as he has shown earlier, there exists $M$ such that $\vert c_n z^n| \leq M$ for all $n$.

Pick $w$ such that $R<\vert w| < \vert z|$. Then
$\vert c_n w^n| = \vert c_n z^n|\vert \frac {w^n}{z^n}| \leq M \vert \frac {w}{z}|^n$.

The geometric series $\sum \vert \frac {w}{z}|^n$ converges, because $\vert \frac {w}{z}|< 1$. Hence, by the Comparison test, $\sum\vert c_n w^n|$ converges. This contradicts the definition of $R$.

My problem is that we've already contradicted the definition of $R$ in defining $w$. For a proof by contradiction, wouldn't one need, rather, something that contradicted the original (contrary to fact) assumption? Or is there something about the Comparison test that I have failed to understand?

---

> [image]
>
> [image]
>
> [image]

Comment: That definition is incorrect, it ought to be $R := \sup \{ \lvert z-a\rvert : \ldots\}$ (or the condition ought to be convergence of $\sum \lvert c_nz^n\rvert$). If that is fixed, $R$ is defined by *absolute* convergence, and in part $(2)$, it is assumed that the series converges, but not necessarily absolutely for $z$.

Comment: @ Jack Thank you for giving the original Priestley, including the lemma. I didn't know how to do that.

Comment: @JesseMadnick Jack has kindly provided the original lemma and proof which I should have done, but didn't know how.

Comment: @ Daniel Fischer On page 69 Priestley seems to be saying that  ∑|cnzn| (oh dear copying yours didn't work. I can't find how to do this. MathJax didn't work either) if it converges, converges absolutely, that being what the |c_nz^n| (real) rather than complex form c_nz^n tells you. Is that incorrect? (Even I, who know so little, have found mistakes in Priestly. There may be lots. Not what a learner needs.)

Comment: @Kang: Both parts of the proof appear correct to me.  I don't see any issue with either of them (maybe except for the fact that I don't know what 6.1(1) refers to).  At any rate, I don't see any issue in part (2) in choosing a complex number $w \in \mathbb{C}$ for which $R < |w| < |z|$.

Comment: @JesseMadnick My problem was that $ z$ had already been chosen to exceed $R$, so was already in contradiction with the definition of $R$. Since $w$ is between $z$ and $R$ it too, it seems, was $ chosen$ to be in contradiction with the definition of $R$. There's something a bit subtle for me here, obviously. This is the elucidation I was hoping for when I posted the question. (Though it was also in my mind that there might be a misprint. Thank you for ruling that out!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Daniel Fischer's comment seems to be the answer.

I think you are confusing the convergence of $\sum c_n z^n$ with the convergence of $\sum |c_n z^n|$.  These are different things.  The "Radius of Convergence Lemma" is about the convergence of $\sum c_n z^n$.  But the number $R$ is defined in terms of the convergence of $\sum |c_n z^n|$.

Let's look at the proof of (2).  When the proof begins, we assume for contradiction that the statement of (2) is false, meaning that there exists $z \in \mathbb{C}$ for which $|z| > R$ and $\sum c_n z^n$ converges.  This does not contradict the definition of $R$, which pertains to the convergence of $\sum |c_n z^n|$.

We then choose a number $w \in \mathbb{C}$ for which $R < |w| < |z|$.  There is again no contradiction here: there are plenty of complex numbers $w \in \mathbb{C}$ for which $R < |w| < |z|$.  Nothing about the convergence of $\sum c_n w^n$ or $\sum |c_n w^n|$ is assumed: the complex number $w \in \mathbb{C}$ whose magnitude is between $R$ and $|z|$ is totally arbitrary.

Anyway, one then goes on to *show* that, in fact, $\sum |c_n w^n|$ converges.  The convergence of this series --- notice the absolute value bars --- **does** contradict the definition of $R$, which completes the proof.